# google sheet custom function to reverse array(range)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

this is simplified version of my input and output:
[image]

I have added this custom function to do the reverse but it has no effect.

```
function ReverseRange(inputRange) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(inputRange);
  return range
  .getValues()
  .reverse()
  ;
}
```

Comment: May I ask why are you doing it with GAS after you done with formula?

Comment: dear @idfurw the formula version was handy but it was big. I am working on a complex Business Plan with thousands of records and I need simpler solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function ReverseRange(inputRange) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(inputRange);
  var values = range.getValues();
  return [values[0].reverse()];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the answer from @idfurw solved the problem. Based on his answer I found that I can define a function without the need to call by reference. This is the version that works by value:

```
function ReverseRangeByValue(inputRange) {
  return [inputRange[0].reverse()];
}
```

Here is how I call it:

```
=ReverseRangeByValue(B15:D15)
```